# Wordpress > Exclude specific categories from categories listing

Tags: php

I have created some functional categories that I use to show/hide markup elements. However, when I go to list the legit categories, these show up too, which I would expect. I want to list the legitimate categories and omit others.

I need to know how you would do it under two circumstances....

1) Each category that I want to exclude is preceded by an underscore character in its name.

2) Each category that I want to exclude is NOT preceeded by a special character and I will just provide an ID to the script that handles the exclusion listing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A check over at the codex for the wp_list_categories template tag (http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) describes three parameters of `wp_list_categories()` that allow you to control the inclusion or exclusion of categories.

> exclude 
>       (string) Exclude one or more categories from the results. This
>   parameter takes a comma-separated list
>   of categories by unique ID, in
>   ascending order. See the example. The
>   child_of parameter is automatically
>   set to false.
>
> exclude_tree 
>       (string) Exclude category-tree from the results. This parameter added
>   at Version 2.7.1
>
> include 
>       (string) Only include the categories detailed in a
>   comma-separated list by unique ID, in
>   ascending order. See the example.

You might have checked this already, and maybe you are looking for a more dynamic way to exclude categories with the prefix you describe.
A: you could hard-code the categories you want to exclude in your call to `wp_list_categories()`.

B: you could write a function that loops through the category names (using [`get_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) and create a comma separated string of of the category id's that `preg_match()` the prefix you designated.  Pass the string to wp_list_categories argument under the exclude parameter.

Comment: I think you are on the right track with B. That's the approach I was looking for. Thanks for the tips!